# How to do you access root folder of a USB drive?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android 10 running on Raspberry Pi 3B (Lineage OS). When I connect a USB stick to the Pi, I can see the contents of the USB stick in the "Files" app.

I'm trying to convert an old app of mine so that I can read data from the USB stick. I used to be able to do this easy enough with Android 4/5 on my car radio.

I am using API 29 and have the following permissions set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```

How can I access the USB drive using legacy file spec? Multiple USB drive can be connected, so how would I enumerate the volumes and then access files and folders?

```
String pathTop = "<path of one of the USB drive root folders>";
File fFolder = new File( pathTop );
File file[] = fFolder.listFiles();
```

Comment: Try SAF wirh ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @blackapps What's SAF?

Comment: If you dont know then just use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps. This will do the job! I was wanting to convert my own file browser but I can live with this if there is no other way of doing it.

Comment: If the usb drive is not in getExternalFilesDirs() then you have to use SAF.